# Word for a situation in which only part of a text or quote is given, giving it a new meaning

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a word for a situation in which a person takes out only a specific meaning, omitting the rest of a given statement, essay, or factual writing.
For example, read the sentence below:

> I will shoot the dog if it attacks me again.

If I only take out the first half, "I will shoot the dog", and spread it among people that the above person is a cruel dog hater and he wants to shoot dogs, what would this be called?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by others, **"taking things out of context"** could work. If you need a single (albeit formal) word, there's always **decontextualize**, although I wouldn't use it in colloquial speech.

> decontextualize: to remove from a context

([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decontextualize))

If the person in your example knowingly spread false rumors, verbs such as **twist** or **misrepresent** could work:

> twist: to **change the true or intended meaning of a statement**, especially in order to get some advantage for yourself

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/twist_1))

> misrepresent: to **deliberately give a wrong description** of someone’s opinions or of a situation

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/misrepresent))

Comment: Yes, nice summary. The situation presented by the OP is a misrepresentation of the original statement—words taken out of context, or decontextualized, with the clear intent of twisting their meaning. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is called '[**contextomy**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contextomy)':

> 1. the practice of misquoting someone by shortening the quotation or by leaving out surrounding words or sentences that would place the quotation in context.
> 2. an instance of this.

The journal article '*Quoted Out of Context: Contextomy and Its Consequences*' on [Oxford Academic](https://academic.oup.com/joc/article-abstract/55/2/330/4103017?redirectedFrom=fulltext) describes it as follows:

> “Contextomy” refers to the excerpting of words from their original linguistic context in a way that distorts the source's intentions.

While not a particularly common word, it does exactly describe the situation you are sketching.

Comment: Yes, and it's an exact fit to _this_ question. // Good edit too.

Comment: (@EdwinAshworth, as opposed to the other question? And thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would call that "quoting out of context", or "taking out of context" … but I don't know of a single word for such an action.

Comment: Also perhaps "misquoting".